# How to update a table created by query in Standard SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have created a table in Standard SQL. In this table, I have a column named COUNTRY. In the results, I saw that I have Brazil and Brasil, and also United Kingdom and Great Britan, so I want to update one of them to match the other, because it is the same for the analysis I want to do. Any ideas?

Comment: As an aside, GB -> UK is normally a safe bet but UK ->GB can be risky!

Answer (score 0):

You can update a table:

```
update t
    set country = (case when country = 'Brasil' then 'Brazil'
                        when country = 'Great Britain' then 'United Kingdom'
                        else country
                   end)
    where country in ('Brasil', 'Great Britain');
```

However, it might be simpler to modify your query so the next time you create the table the countries will be correct.

Comment: `Else` is not required.

Comment: So, in order to save the results of the table in t, I have to use WITH t AS... . And in this case, I can't use the update

Comment: @JamesHarrington . . . The question says that you have created a table.  This answers the question that you have asked.  If you have a different question, then ask as a *new* question.  This question has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly what you want, you can use :

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET COUNTRY = 'Great Britan'
WHERE COUNTRY = 'United Kingdom'
```

This changes every 'United Kingdom' column to 'Great Britan'

Comment: So, in order to save the results of the table in yourTable, I have to use WITH yourTable AS... . And in this case, I can't use the update.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
update your_table t
set country = d.country 
from (
  select 'Brazil' country, 'Brasil' matches union all
  select 'United Kingdom', 'UK|Great Britain|GB' union all
  select 'USA', 'US'
) d 
where t.country in unnest(split(matches, '|'));
```